# angularjs checkbox filter on expression

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-filter

I'm trying to filter if the value is greater than 0 in my ng-repeat on a single checkbox, so I'd like to just be able to do this:

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="filter.uid" ng-true-value=">0" ng-false-value="0">filter if uid > 0
```

But, ng-true-value and ng-false-value do not take expressions... So I'm guessing that I need to create a custom filter?  This seems like it should be trivial but I just want to check if I'm missing something..

Here's a link to my jsFiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/webmastersean/4m2d5n8u/39/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the true-/false-value is assigned to your model `filter.uid` the value ">0" can't be used.

You can store the checkbox value in a variable, e.g. `filterActive`, and use a filter function in your ngRepeat:

```
$scope.filter = function(entry) {
    if($scope.filterActive) {
        return (entry.uid > 0) ? true: false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Check out the fork: https://jsfiddle.net/49qgbdk6/

Comment: Thanks Sebastian, that works!  However after clicking the clearFilter it breaks so trying ti fix that now :-/

Comment: If you want to use multiple filter options, save them to an own variable (like you did previously), e.g. `$scope.filterOptions`, and add the logic to the filter function. https://jsfiddle.net/49qgbdk6/2/

Answer (score 0):

The built-in `filter` filter supports only negation for the predicate. If your numbers are never negative, you could filter on "not `0`":

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="filter.uid" 
       ng-true-value="'!0'" ng-false-value="">

<div ng-repeat="project in projects | filter: filter></div>
```

[Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/VWGgtZNuPBTr7bPfJfXC?p=preview)

Clearly, this would only work for `>0`. For any other scenario (for example, `>1`) you would need a custom filter expression.